# Instabug Compilation Error in Gradle Build Tools ver 2+

Tags: android, gradle, compiler-errors, instabug

Since increasing the build gradle tools version to version 2 aboves, I've experience a lot of compilation error in Android Studio(more than 500). The weird things is, the project is still runnable, and function properly.

```
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.instabug.library.activity.b) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

Appreciate any help..

Answer (score 0):

These issues should disappear if you just upgrade to latest version v2.3.3 (at the time of writing)

Please let me know if you have any more questions :)